# Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence: XML saved as String varible

Tags: java, xml, encode

I get the following error due to Latin text in my XML.

> Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence: XML saved as String varible

My XML is written to a String variable (I don't import a file). 
I tried to set encoding to "UTF-8", but I might have done it wrong.

Can you help please?

**My code:**

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(GET_XML.getBytes());
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputStream);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Would you mind posting the code that creates `GET_XML`? Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this error, because you are feeding xml containing ISO-8859-1 (aka Latin-1) characters without proper XML declaration:
`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' standalone='no' ?>`

You have two options either correct it by sourcing xml with above declaration.

OR forcing `UTF-8` during byte conversion.
`new ByteArrayInputStream(GET_XML.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`